# Cross Join in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

I have two ranges in excel.  I'm looking for a simpler way to combine each row of Range1 with each row of Range2.   The number of columns and rows in each range can change.  Refer image below

Can it be done only with Macro or is there way to do it in normal or dynamic array formulas.

Or do you suggest a dynamic array UDF

[image]

Comment: vba will be the best.  Use two nested loops that iterate the rows and creates the output.

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
=LET( repliRange, D1:F3,
      byRange, A1:B2,
        rpR, ROWS( repliRange ),
        rpC, COLUMNS( repliRange ),
        byC, COLUMNS( byRange ),
        rIdx, SEQUENCE( rpR * ROWS( byRange ),,0 ),
        cIdx, SEQUENCE( 1, rpC + byC, 0 ),
        mux, INDEX( repliRange, MOD( rIdx, rpR ) + 1, SEQUENCE( 1, rpC, 0 )+1 ),
        noVBA, IF( cIdx < byC, INDEX( byRange, rIdx/rpR+1, cIdx + 1),
                               INDEX( mux, MOD(rIdx,rpC)+1, cIdx-1) ),
        noVBA )
```

*Excel 365 required.*

Where D1:F3 are the right side array (**repliRange**) that you want cross-joined to the left side **byRange** of A1:B2.  It will take nearly any number of rows and columns on either side.  Perhaps the variable order would be more logical the other way, but I assumed a sentence logic of *"replicate D1:F3 by A1:B2"*.

**Non-LET Version**

```
=IF( SEQUENCE( 1, COLUMNS( D1:F3 ) + COLUMNS( A1:B2 ), 0 ) < COLUMNS( A1:B2 ),
    INDEX( A1:B2,
           SEQUENCE( ROWS( D1:F3 ) * ROWS( A1:B2 ),,0 )/ROWS( D1:F3 )+1,
           SEQUENCE( 1, COLUMNS( D1:F3 ) + COLUMNS( A1:B2 ), 0 ) + 1),
    INDEX( INDEX( D1:F3,
                  MOD( SEQUENCE( ROWS( D1:F3 ) * ROWS( A1:B2 ),,0 ), ROWS( D1:F3 ) ) + 1,
                  SEQUENCE( 1, COLUMNS( D1:F3 ), 0 )+1 ),
           MOD(SEQUENCE( ROWS( D1:F3 ) * ROWS( A1:B2 ),,0 ),COLUMNS( D1:F3 ))+1,
           SEQUENCE( 1, COLUMNS( D1:F3 ) + COLUMNS( A1:B2 ), 0 )-1) )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks... Unfortunately, my excel 365 is yet to get the update relating to "Let" function.

Comment: @TheKing Quel dommage. It is really helpful and sometimes even essential. If it is of any help, I will post the non-LET version, but it would be maddeningly difficult to update it with your inputs.

Comment: In the LET-version your MOD in the second index range of `NoVBA`: `MOD(rIdx,byC)+1` gets divided by the number of columns of the byRange (`byC`) instead of the the number of columns of the repliRange (`rpC`). `MOD(rIdx,rpC)+1` would return the desired spill result.

Comment: Hi @P.b - Nice catch! As you can see from the screenshot, it originally had 4 which was a remnant of my testing & debugging. I published it with the remnant and forgot - then I saw my mistake and "fixed it" with... a different mistake. I'll fix it now with your proposal - you are spot on. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the sol.. I think it's best to use VBA and write a UDF :)

Comment: Sure @TheKing - where VBA can work, it offers a plethora of capabilities. LET (and eventually LAMBDA) will clear a path for non-VBA solutions. They are not necessarily easier, but VBA is quite frequently an unacceptable method. That path will be there, but it will not be wide. VBA (or Python, JS, etc.) will be the ultimate back-stop. Thanks for the feedback and question. It was a good one.

Comment: I think the second part of the final `IF` statement should use `rpR` instead of `rpC` in the `MOD` function. So:
`INDEX( mux, MOD(rIdx, rpC)+1, cIdx-1)`
Should be:
`INDEX( mux, MOD(rIdx, rpR)+1, cIdx-1)`

Answer (score 3):

```
= LAMBDA(RangeFrom, RangeTo,
      LET(repliRange, RangeTo, byRange, RangeFrom, 
rpR, ROWS(repliRange), 
rpC, COLUMNS(repliRange), 
byC, COLUMNS(byRange), 
rIdx, SEQUENCE(rpR * ROWS(byRange), , 0),
cIdx, SEQUENCE(1, rpC + byC, 0), 
To, INDEX(repliRange, MOD(rIdx, rpR) + 1, SEQUENCE(1, rpC, 0) + 1), From, TAKE(INDEX(byRange, rIdx / rpR + 1, cIdx + 1), , byC),
HSTACK(From, To)))
```

This lambda version will work with both 1-dimension and n-dimension arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
=INDEX(
(A1:B2,D1:F3),
LET(x,SEQUENCE(6),IF(SEQUENCE(1,5)<3,1+FLOOR((x-1)/3,1),1+MOD(x-1,3))),
{1,2,1,2,3},
{1,1,2,2,2}
)
```

[image: cross join]

The `LET` row sequence is

[image: data for rows]

which does the nesting.

Then the `column` and `area` parameters repeat.

Answer (score 0):

This is the formula I use for arrays, but I guess it can be modified for range.

```
=TEXTSPLIT(
ARRAYTOTEXT(
TOCOL(Array_1) & "|" & TOROW(Array_2), 0), "|", ", ")
```

[Example with range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0mLN.png)