# Sorted aggregation table by one dynamic array formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have raw data in B3:C11. In Column F, I would like to sum up the number in Column C for each person, then sort the table by the sum.

[image]

Could anyone find **only one** dynamic array formula for E3 to achieve this (without borrowing intermediate cells)?

Comment: I'd suggest using a Pivot table instead of a formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different approach using LET:
`=LET(x,FILTER(B:B,B:B<>""),y,UNIQUE(x),SORT(IF(SEQUENCE(1,2)<=COLUMNS(x),y,SUMIF(B:B,INDEX(y,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(y))),C:C)),2,-1))`
[image]

Comment: Yeah I did, inspired by your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68213486/cross-join-in-excel

Comment: My thought was: `=LET( names, B3:B11,
 vals, C3:C11,
 uNames, UNIQUE( names ),
 piv, SUMIF(names, uNames, vals),
 table, CHOOSE( {1,2}, uNames, piv ),
 SORTBY( table, INDEX( table, , 2), - 1 ) ) `, which is really just a variation of yours, but I am using a PC and no way I would be able to do it on a phone. Really - well done.

Comment: Ok, I like the use of CHOOSE I never used it before.

Comment: It's a great way to bind single columns into a dynamic array: CHOOSE({1,2,...,N}),colArray1, colArray2,...colArrayN). If you want to bind multi column arrays, it can be done with IFERROR and/or IF with a column or row index. This is useful (but mind-crushing) when you need to glue sections together to form a complex dynamic array.

Answer (score 2):

Little bit stress but achievable.

```
=INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,SORTBY(UNIQUE(B3:B11),SUMIF(B3:B11,UNIQUE(B3:B11),C3:C11),-1),SORT(SUMIF(B3:B11,UNIQUE(B3:B11),C3:C11),,-1))&"</s></t>","//s"),TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(UNIQUE(B3:B11))/2,COUNTA(UNIQUE(B3:B11)))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this counts as only one, but you could do

`=SORTBY(UNIQUE($B$3:$B$11), SUMIF($B$3:$B$11, UNIQUE($B$3:$B$11), $C$3:$C$11),-1)` in E3 and then `SUMIF` those values in F3.